# Elastic search query to don't want to consider the comma.

Tags: elasticsearch

Example:
 Node name: "description"
 containing string "sample,"

I have to get results for both "sample," and "sample" queries.
How to do this Analyser and Mapping part in settings?
I am new to Elastic search. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your mapping to be of type "text" the default analyzer should do the job.

i.e.

```
{
  "description":{
    "type":"text"
    }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html